# Extraction of common element in given arrays to make a new array

Tags: python, numpy

In the example below, data1, data2, and data3 are the given arrays. Now, I have to find out the element which exist in all the given arrays. Then, I have to make new array including only those common elements, and assigning all other elements as nan value.

import numpy as np

```
data1 = np.array ([[1,2,33,4,33,6],[7,8,9,10,93,12]])
data2 = np.array ([[1,14,33,15,33,17],[18,19,20,21,93,23]])
data3 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
```

The required result is shown below as the result array: Only the values 33 and 93 are available into all the given arrays at the same position (i.e., they should be overlapped). In other words, I have to find out only overlapped elements with the same values from each array here.

```
result = np.array([[nan,nan,33,nan,nan,nan],[nan,nan,nan,nan,93,nan]])
```

I am expecting an efficient way of calculating it. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Boolean indexing

```
import numpy as np
result = np.empty_like(data1, dtype=float)
# Make an array of True-False values storing which indices are the same
indices = (data1==data2) * (data2==data3)
result[indices] = data1[indices]
result[~indices] = np.nan
```

If you have more arrays, you can do something like this:
(assuming the arrays are in a list)

```
# construct the list of arrays
data = []
for i in xrange(8):
    data.append(np.random.randint(0,2, (20, 20)))
indices = data[0] == data[1]
for i in xrange(2, 8):
    indices *= (data[0] == data[i])
result = np.empty_like(data[1], dtype=float)
result[indices] = data1[indices]
result[~indices] = np.nan
result
```

It would be much better, however, if each array were just a slice of a 3D array.
It was shown in another answer that, given several arrays, you can make a 3D array from them and then use `np.where`.
That is a valid approach.
I'll show how to do this with array broadcasting here.
In this case we can do the following

```
# construct 3D array with random data
# each data array will be a slice of this array, e.g. data[0], data[1], etc.
data = np.random.randint(0, 3, (3, 4, 5))
# make an empty array to store the results as before
result = np.empty_like(data[0], dtype=float)
# use broadcasting to test for equality
indices = np.all(data == data[0], axis=0)
# Do the assignment as before
result[indices] = data[0][indices]
result[~indices] = np.nan
result
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts. however i have received the following value error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:/t.py", line 12, in <module>
    result[~indices] = np.nan
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: Yep, I fixed that in an edit. The array `result` needs to have a floating point data type to store `nan` values.

Comment: by the way, if i have more than 3 given array (say 10 arrays). Then how can I?

Comment: Hmm. The best way I can think of for multiple arrays is a for loop. If you have them all as elements of a 3d array or something of that sort you can use array broadcasting instead. That is probably a better bet.

Comment: I'll just add the answer here.