# Extraction of common element from multiple arrays to make a new array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

In the example below, data1, data2, ...data10 are the given arrays. Now, I have to find out the element which exist in all the given arrays. Then, I have to make new array including only those common elements, and assigning all other elements as nan value.

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array ([[1,2,33,4,33,6],[7,8,9,10,93,12]])
data2 = np.array ([[1,14,33,15,33,17],[18,19,20,21,93,23]])
data3 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data4 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data5 = np.array ([[67,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data6 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data7 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,51,93,34]])
data8 = np.array ([[48,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]]) 
data9 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,38]]) 
data10 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[73,30,31,32,93,34]])
```

The required result is shown below as the result array: Only the values 33 and 93 are available into all the given arrays at the same position (i.e., they should be overlapped). In other words, I have to find out only overlapped elements with the same values from each array here.

`result = np.array([[nan,nan,33,nan,nan,nan],[nan,nan,nan,nan,93,nan]])`

NOTE: In case a few given arrays(say 3), the following code which was answered in the following question works.
[Extraction of common element in given arrays to make a new array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642748/extraction-of-common-element-in-given-arrays-to-make-a-new-array)

```
import numpy as np
result = np.empty_like(data1, dtype=float)
# Make an array of True-False values storing which indices are the same
indices = (data1==data2) * (data2==data3)
result[indices] = data1[indices]
result[~indices] = np.nan
```

However, when the given arrays are many (say 10), what will be an efficient way of calculating it. Any idea would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `numpy` way:

```
import numpy as np
data1 = np.array ([[1,2,33,4,33,6],[7,8,9,10,93,12]])
data2 = np.array ([[1,14,33,15,33,17],[18,19,20,21,93,23]])
data3 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data4 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data5 = np.array ([[67,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data6 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data7 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,51,93,34]])
data8 = np.array ([[48,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,34]])
data9 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[93,30,31,32,93,38]])
data0 = np.array ([[24,25,33,26,1,28],[73,30,31,32,93,34]])
data=np.dstack((data1, data2, data3,data4,data5,data6,data7,data8,data9,data0))
np.where(np.all(np.equal(data, data1[...,np.newaxis]), axis=2), data1, np.nan)
```

`equal` does element wise comparison and resulting an array of the same shape as `data`.

`all` then picks up the positions where all the values are equal to the `data1`

`where` takes 3 arguments `(x1,x2,x3)`: where `x1` true, the resulting array get the value from `x2`; where `x1` is false, the resulting array get the value from `x3`

Result

```
Out[22]:
array([[ nan,  nan,  33.,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan,  93.,  nan]])
```

Comment: looks interesting, could you please explain your code, too many use of numpy builtin functions in the same line is confusing for me.

Comment: what is the meaning of [...,np.newaxis]?

Comment: It is for broadcasting. `data1` is 2D and `data` is 3D so `data1` is one dimension less. Without broadcasting they will not align properly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible I would really recommend initializing things like this as a single array. That approach is shown in my answer to the other question.

Modifying my answer to the other question, here is how you would use broadcasting and fancy indexing in this case.

```
# construct 3D array with random data
# each data array will be a slice of this array, e.g. data[:,:,0], data[:,:,1], etc.
data = np.dstack((data1, data2, data3, data4, data5, data6, data7, data8, data9, data0))
# make an empty array to store the results as before
result = np.empty_like(data[:,:,0], dtype=float)
# use broadcasting to test for equality
# Note the slicing by range in the third dimension to keep dimensions aligned
# for broadcasting to work properly.
indices = np.all(data == data[:,:,0:1], axis=-1)
# Do the assignment as before
result[indices] = data[:,:,0][indices]
result[~indices] = np.nan
result
```

Again, this is equivalent to the approach with `np.where` shown in another answer, but I prefer the boolean indexing for the sake of readability even though it may be marginally slower.

Answer (score 0):

f you are able to find the common elements between two arrays, you should be able to use the result array to use for further indexing purposes. This is also quite efficient. (If n = numArrays, m=lengthArray, worst case: O(n*m), best case: O(m)

So something like this:

```
allCommon = reduce(find_common_elements_in_two_arrays, allArrays)
```